# Reference used library in Java import

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

I added two external .Jar's to my Java project which have the same package and file names. Now is the Question if it is possible to reference which of the Packages/Classes I want to use in an import Statement? I'm using IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

It will load the one appears in the classpath that specified first.

From specification

> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the directories in the order they appear in the class path variable

So not possible via import directly... it actually depends on the order that dependencies appears in your classpath...